# Filepath in foreach controller is not working in JMeter

Tags: jmeter

Am using a "filepath" in my foreach controller using  using `__V()` and `__counter()`.

Declaration in Postprocessor for **file-path** :

```
def filePathListArrayList = vars.getObject("pathValue");

1.upto(filePathListArrayList.size(), { vars.put('filePathUUIDA_' + it, filePathListArrayList.get(it - 1).toString())})
```

Code in the `JSR223 sampler` inside the for-each controller,

Approach 1:

```
def filePathOfImageDir = new File("${__V(filePathUUIDA_${__counter(,)})}")
def InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(filePathOfImageDir );
requestBuilder.setEntity(entity); (note: this is just a piece of my code)
```

Error Details:

```
2023-07-16 13:27:17,492 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script ImageUpload, message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script914.groovy: 32: Unexpected character: '"' @ line 32, column 35.
   def filePathOfImageDir = new File("C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_0.img")
                                     ^

1 error
```

Approach 2:

```
def filePathOfImageDir = new File(${__V(filePathUUIDA_${__counter(,)})})
def InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(filePathOfImageDir );
    requestBuilder.setEntity(entity);
```

Error Details:

```
2023-07-16 13:29:47,507 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script ImageUpload, message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script941.groovy: 32: Unexpected character: '\' @ line 32, column 37.
   def filePathOfImageDir = new File(C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_0.img)
                                       ^

1 error
```

Approach 3:

```
def imageDirectory = "${__V(filePathUUIDA_${__counter(,)})}";

def InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(imageDirectory);
requestBuilder.setEntity(entity);
```

Error Details:

```
2023-07-16 13:43:44,027 ERROR o.a.j.p.j.s.JSR223Sampler: Problem in JSR223 script ImageUpload, message: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
Script995.groovy: 34: Unexpected character: '"' @ line 34, column 22.
   def imageDirectory = "C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_0.img";
                        ^

1 error
```

Approach 4:

```
def imageDirectory = ${__V(filePathUUIDA_${__counter(,)})};
def InputStreamEntity entity = new InputStreamEntity(new FileInputStream(imageDirectory);
requestBuilder.setEntity(entity);
```

Error details:

```
Script1022.groovy: 34: Unexpected input: ':' @ line 34, column 23.
   def imageDirectory = C:\PerformanceTestFiles\555210_98168_98980_0.img;
                         ^

1 error

javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed:
```

Tried wit replacing '' with '\' using `String filePathOfImage = vars.get("${__V(filePathUUIDA_${__counter(,)})}").replaceAll("\\\\","\\\\\\\\");`
but not working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Don't inline JMeter Functions or Variables into Groovy scripts because:

1. They can be resolved into something causing compilation failure like in your case
2. Only first occurrence will be cached and used for subsequent iterations
3. There is no need to use __counter() function as [ForEach Controller](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#ForEach_Controller) exposes a special variable holding current loop index (zero-based)

   > JMeter will expose the looping index as a variable named **jm**__idx. So for example, if your Loop Controller is named FEC, then you can access the looping index through ${__jm__FEC__idx}. Index starts at 0

So if you amend your code as follows:

```
vars.get('filePathUUIDA_' + ((vars.get('__jm__ForEach Controller__idx') as int) + 1))
```

it should start working

More information:

- [JSR223 Sampler](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSR223_Sampler)
- [Apache Groovy: What Is Groovy Used For?](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-groovy)

Comment: I am getting "Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead
javax.script.ScriptException: javax.script.ScriptException: org.codehaus.groovy.runtime.typehandling.GroovyCastException: Cannot cast object 'null' with class 'null' to class 'int'. Try 'java.lang.Integer' instead
"

Comment: Take a look what variables are defined using [Debug Sampler](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/debug-jmeter), my example assumes that your ForEach Controller has its default name of `ForEach Controller`. The Groovy code must be [inside](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/test_plan.html#scoping_rules) the ForEach Controller in order to work.

Comment: It worked, I have given "namespace_iterator" which I changed it worked. Thanks dimitri. will replaceAll('////','////////') will work on it ?